# Select Master Data From Table Based on Categories From Multiple Tables

Tags: sql

I have Tables Like

1) User Which Holds The Master Data Like

```
User ID   Name    OtherColumns
1         Banshi   Nothing
2         Banshi2  Nothing 
3         Banshi3  Nothing
```

---

2)Second Table "Friends" Holds Data Like

```
ID    UserID     FriendID    FriendCategory
1       1          2             2
2       2          1             2
3       4          1             2
4       1          4             2
```

---

3)Third Table "Subscribers" Holds Data Like

```
ID    SubscribersID  SubscribToID    FriendCategory
1       1              3                  3
2       1              4                  3
```

---

4)Fourth Table "FriendCategory" Like

```
ID      Name
2       Friends
3       Subscribers
```

---

5)Fifth Table "Posts" Contains Data Like

```
PostID   UserID  Post           
1         2      Hello Dear Post By Banshi2
2         3      Hello Dear  Post By Banshi3
3         4     Hello Dear  Post By Banshi4
```

---

Now Being User 1 i Need Data Like
A) I need Data if Posted By My Friends
B) I need Data if Posted By i am Subscribed to
c) If User is My Friend Subscribed as Well Then it Must Show Friend not i am Subscribed

### My Data Something Like

```
UserID      Name        Post                          Category
2          Banshi2    Hello Dear Post By Banshi2     Friends
3          Banshi3    Hello Dear Post By Banshi3     I Am Subcriber 
4          Banshi4    Hello Dear Post By Banshi4     Friends
```

Please Suugest Me How to Get Such a Out put in Sql Server 2008

Thanks in Advance
Banshi

Comment: please tell your final output/column ??

Comment: According to your current data for `friendCategory` in `Friends` table, it has no match in `Subscribers` table for `FriendCategory`..please confirm if your sample data is accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting data if posted by friends

```
SELECT
  u.UserID, u.Name , p.Post , fc.Name 
FROM
  users as u,
  FriendCategory as fc,
  Subscribers as s,
  Friends as f,
  Posts as p 
WHERE
  f.UserID=1
  and fc.id=f.FriendCategory
  and p.UserID = f.FriendID
group by fc.Name
```

You can do it similarly for getting data to i am subscribedto .

> c) If User is My Friend Subscribed as Well Then it Must Show Friend
>   not i am Subscribed

Well, i didn't get what you were trying to say here .

Comment: you're welcome :) it's perfectly normal here to edit other people posts :) i only wanted to improve the formatting a little! welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure can you try this and let me know,

```
select u.userid,u.name,p.post,f.name from 
User u join Friends fr on u.userid=fr.userid
join FriendCategory f on fr.FriendID=f.id
join Posts p on u.userid=p.userid
order by u.userid;
```

Comment: Hi I need posts from those as well for whole i have subscribed Say For Example I and Friend With Banshi 2 and Subscriber for Banshi 3 i need Both of Posts , and One More thing if I am friend With Banshi4 and Subscriber for the Same it Must Show Friends As a Category.